# Use C++ code in xamarin Android, iOS and UWP

Tags: android, c++, ios, xamarin

I have a xamarin project which runs on Android, iOS and Windows Phone 10. This project is write in c#. 
And I want add a C++ in my solution and each project can use C++ function thanks to Interrop. I can add a c++ project on Android and iOS by adding a shared library but but I can not add it to my UWP project. If I want use a C++ library I need to use a Windows Runtime Component. But I want just 1 shared code for Android, iOS and UWP, I think I need to create a dynamic or static library but I do not know how then reference it in my UWP project.